# How to use SVN hook (pre commit script for code review) with xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, svn-hooks

I have been trying to use SVN hook (pre-commit validation script) to incorporate validation of compulsory coding standard while code committing in our project (in Objective C).
It would really help if you can share your experience/knowledge regarding this.